# How to find city names and person names from unstructured data in python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to find the city names and person names from another unstructured data files. We have many text files.

How to find such string in using pandas or python

for example:

I have to find a string `Ram` and `Mumbai` from another unstructured data file.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You are looking for "named entity recognition" (NER). You can try an NLP toolkit like Stanford CoreNLP, NLTK, or Spacy. For person names, you can try a library called "probablepeople".

Answer (score -1):

You could use Python Pandas, read csv and some code like this (from the pandas docs).

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series(['Mouse', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN])
>>> s1.str.contains('og', regex=False)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4      NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: This only works if you have a limited set of names you know you want to check, and the text data is very clean.

Comment: @shadowtalker agreed, some data cleaning is probably needed.